# Protect authenticated PHP session from Session Hijacking through packet sniffing

Tags: php, sessionid, session-hijacking

I am interested in the subject of securing PHP sessions, without the use of SSL.

For my surprise, if a man-in-the-middle sniffs the packets exchanged between the user and the server it is very easy to steal the session, even if it is authenticated . I know that there are some tactics to limit damages, such as, changing sessionid when logging in/logging out, recording/checking user system parameters (e.g. OS, browser).

However if during a session ,which is already authenticated and not logged out (there was no time for time out also), the attacker is able to get the session id, then he can easily hijack the session (as far as I understand the problem).

I thought about a possible solution, where during the login authentication which is ciphered, the server could send a random session-password to the client. The session-password would be only valid during that login session. So every message exchanged during that session had to be signed using the session-password (e.g. MD5(session-password+message-contents)).

Is the problem fixed? What are the weaknesses of this approach, assuming the attacker is not able to crypt-analyse the initial login exchange?

Comment: No offense, but consider just using SSL... it may cost around $49 - $100 a year, but it's much cheaper than having to pay developers to maintain a custom `security scheme`

Comment: +1. Also, @João Salada, how will the random session password be sent without SSL?

Comment: no offence! ;) I just want to develop my blog from scratch so I can understand what are the major problems, like this one. but using ssl is a huge overkill when you don't need to have confidentiality (my opinion). This scheme I though about seems very simple though... That's why I wanted to ask if it solves the problem or it is flawed..

Comment: Apart from confidentiality , SSL ensures data integrity ( not modified during data transfer ) . You should use it .

Comment: I understand zi42 question. If the man-in-the-middle intercepts the login response from the client, he is still able to impersonate the client. and the server would send the session-password to the wrong guy, right? However he would have to know the client password...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed "signing" solution requires client-side behaviour - you therefore need a client-side application that can do the signing.

If you're writing Flash/Java applet/Unity or any of those plug-ins, then you can follow your plan as you can control the client more closely and add routines to do the signing.

But I assume you're delievering HTML pages to a browser without using a plugin? If so, you have two choices, really. The fist is SSL (that you're ruling out) as it's built into the browser. The second is Javascript. For maximum security you need to somehow mimic SSL, including with client-side storage of the encryption (public) key / algorythm (so that they never travel together with the messages). You'd want to get as close to the public/private key + handshaking of SSL as possible - which is no mean feat. As suggested by sarnold, you'd want a strong encyption key. Check out http://www.jcryption.org/ for an example - others appear with googling.

If that's a bit over-the-top, your most viable solution would probably to negotiate a simpler encyption algorthym using JS: you send a "key", store "key" in a cookie on browser, all communications via AJAX and you create a simpler  signing machanism based on that key (plus possibly another variable that the client shared with you during an initial handshake). Anything that doesn't decode or match the key, then kill the entire session and start again.

---

sarnold has good points in his answer that md5 and SHA-1 are to be avoided; and some even consider SHA256 to be getting wesk for today's computers, but considering you need to implment a solution in JS, for speed you may be tied to something as "piddly" (my analogy) as md5. So your best defence for this is accurate logging and brute force / error detection. Any messages arriving garbled (and you could check at either end) should be logged and monitored. Too many failures and the IP address gets banned - and keep logging.

Comment: I was thinking the second option, and that website is just what I wanted. ;) The problem with Public/Private key approach which is part of the  SSL and TLS scheme is that it requires a signed certificate which is expensive. If on the other hand, one uses  a certificate not signed by those verisign, etc the browser will return you a big warning, and most of the people will go away. this is for my blog...

Comment: Certificates can be had for as low as about $20 per year. Example: http://www.hostnexus.com/solutions/certificates-compare.php. The only difference in prices is the insurances and guarnatees that come with them, really. You'll spend a lot more than that trying to get the non-ssl solution to work. But if going it alone, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use something like [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) instead of your simpler MD5 -- and you'd want to use SHA256 or larger, since MD5 is known to have weaknesses and SHA-1 is starting to feel weak too.

But even with these changes, your scheme would still be vulnerable to [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), where an attacker could re-send the request over and over again and your server would happily re-execute it every time. This is no big deal if it is just posting photos of the latest beach trip but if it is sending a purchase request for $1000 ponies, someone is going to wind up with a lot more ponies than they might expect.

So you'd need to add a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) to the protocol.

There are liable to be other problems -- after all, TLS is now on version 1.2 after three iterations of SSL. Just stick with TLS and be happy.

Comment: Yes, MD5 is vulnerable to prefix attacks. I used MD5 as an example. But thank you anyway. Just wanted to know  if the scheme has some advantages. and about the nonce you are absolutely correct. Thanks ;)